# Why does macOS kill static executables created by clang?

Tags: macos, clang, mach-o, otool, osx-gatekeeper

I have a minimal c program for the m1 arm cpu that returns 42:

```
void _start() {
    asm("mov x0, #42;");
    asm("mov x16, #1;");
    asm("svc 0x80;");
}
```

This code compiles after telling clang to use the _start symbol and returns the correct value.

```
clang -Wl,-e, -Wl,__start test.c -o dyn.out
./dyn.out ; echo $?
42
```

However this binary still has dynamic links according to otool:

```
otool -L ./dyn.out 
./dyn.out:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.100.3)
```

After telling clang to produce a unsigned static binary however macOS then immediately kills the binary when trying to run.

```
clang -Wl,-e, -Wl,__start -static -nostdlib test.c -o static_no_sign.out
zsh: killed     ./static_no_sign.out
```

Signing the binary before running also produces the same problem.

```
clang -Wl,-e, -Wl,__start -static -nostdlib test.c -o static_sign.out 
codesign -s - static_sign.out 
./static_sign.out 
zsh: killed     ./static_sign.out
```

The following messages are produced in Console:

```
taskgated: UNIX error exception: 3
taskgated: no signature for pid=93166 (cannot make code: UNIX[No such process])
```

But codesign can verify the signature

```
codesign -v -v static_sign.out 
static_sign.out: valid on disk
static_sign.out: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

Can anyone clarify why macOS is deciding to kill the clang produced binaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because static binaries are explicitly disallowed on any architecture other than x86_64.
XNU contains [this code piece](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/a325d9c4a84054e40bbe985afedcb50ab80993ea/bsd/kern/mach_loader.c#L844-L862) in the Mach-O loader:

```c
case MH_EXECUTE:
    if (depth != 1 && depth != 3) {
        return LOAD_FAILURE;
    }
    if (header->flags & MH_DYLDLINK) {
        /* Check properties of dynamic executables */
        if (!(header->flags & MH_PIE) && pie_required(header->cputype, header->cpusubtype & ~CPU_SUBTYPE_MASK)) {
            return LOAD_FAILURE;
        }
        result->needs_dynlinker = TRUE;
    } else if (header->cputype == CPU_TYPE_X86_64) {
        /* x86_64 static binaries allowed */
    } else {
        /* Check properties of static executables (disallowed except for development) */
#if !(DEVELOPMENT || DEBUG)
        return LOAD_FAILURE;
#endif
    }
    break;
```

If you do the exact same thing on x86_64, it works:

```c
void _start()
{
    __asm__ volatile
    (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix\n"
        "mov eax, 0x2000001\n"
        "mov edi, 42\n"
        "syscall"
    );
}
```

```
% clang -Wl,-e,__start -static -nostdlib t.c -o t -arch x86_64
% ./t
% echo $?
42
```