# Why is hello world in assembly for ARM mac 'invalid'?

Tags: macos, assembly, arm, apple-m1, arm64

The other answers don't tell me how to compile, I'm stuck

I have a simple hello world in assembly

```
    .global start
    .align 2

    start: mov X0, #1
        adr     X1, hello
        mov     X2, #13
        mov     X16, #4
        svc     0

        mov     X0, #0
        mov     X16, #1
        svc     0

    hello: .ascii  "Hello\n"
```

I compiled it using `clang hello.s -nostdlib -static`
File says

```
% file ./a.out 
./a.out: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

obj dump shows this and perhaps UNKNOWN_ARCHITECTURE is the problem?

```
    ./a.out:     file format mach-o-arm64


    Disassembly of section .text:

    0000000100003fd8 <start>:
        100003fd8:  d2800020    mov x0, #0x1                    // #1
        100003fdc:  100000e1    adr x1, 100003ff8 <hello>
        100003fe0:  d28001a2    mov x2, #0xd                    // #13
        100003fe4:  d2800090    mov x16, #0x4                       // #4
        100003fe8:  d4000001    svc #0x0
        100003fec:  d2800000    mov x0, #0x0                    // #0
        100003ff0:  d2800030    mov x16, #0x1                       // #1
        100003ff4:  d4000001    svc #0x0

    0000000100003ff8 <hello>:
        100003ff8:  6c6c6548    ldnp    d8, d25, [x10, #-320]
        100003ffc:  Address 0x0000000100003ffc is out of bounds.


    Disassembly of section LC_THREAD.UNKNOWN_ARCHITECTURE.0:

    0000000000000000 <LC_THREAD.UNKNOWN_ARCHITECTURE.0>:
        ...
    100:    00003fd8    udf #16344
    104:    00000001    udf #1
        ...
```

Running in zsh says "killed" with error code 137.

This is what dtruss says

```
    % sudo dtruss ./a.out                                     
    dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available

    dtrace: failed to execute ./a.out: Bad executable (or shared library)
```

Where did I go wrong? I'm on a M2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel on arm64 macOS does not allow static binaries. It's as simple as that, see [Why does macOS kill static executables created by clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71723764/2302862)

But you don't need your binary to be static. Just rename `start` to `_main` and compile with `clang hello.s` and it will work.

Comment: I'm too new to upvote. TY for the answer. Would you happen to know how I might be able to compile this code on linux and run on my mac? I suspect clang on linux can output ARM64 and mach-o (I haven't tried yet). The part I'm clueless about is how to say link to `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` (I got that path by running `otool -L ./a.out`)

Comment: @Stan cross-compiling for Darwin targets is not pretty. Clang is multi-target by default, so you start with `--target=arm64-apple-macos`, but then you need the SDK. You can rip that out of Xcode (`find /Applications/Xcode.app -name MacOSX.sdk`) or the Xcode CLI tools and pass it to clang with `--sysroot=...`. And I'm not sure what the linker defaults are, so you should add `-fuse-ld=ld64.lld` (which you might have to install separately). If that works, great. But it might fail for two common reasons: 1) lld doesn't support even the most basic of options or 2) you don't have libclang_rt.

Comment: I seem to figured out how to build the assembly on linux and use a mach-o linker. Now it looks like I need to set the dylib path -edit- You commented when  I did

Comment: In case 1), refer to [this repo](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/cctools-port) to build Apple's `ld64` and use it with `-fuse-ld=path/to/ld64`. In case 2), download a build of clang+LLVM for Darwin targets, rip the folders with libclang_rt out of them and pass them to clang with `-resource-dir=...` (such that `.../lib/darwin/` has the `.a` files in it).

Comment: I moved onto how to compile it from linux to mac https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74660777/how-to-cross-compile-arm64-assembly-from-linux-to-mac