# I'd like to link malloc/realloc/free without having a lib file

Tags: c, assembly, clang, cross-compiling, apple-m1

If you look at my recent post history I went from hello world assembly to building it on linux and running on mac.

I didn't see an obvious way to implement realloc efficiently. So I'm looking into if I can link it. The issue is I'm not sure if I'm allowed to distribute mac files so I don't think I can distribute a lib file (unless I can build one myself?)

Below is my c code, that's all I'm interested in linking for the moment.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    free(realloc(malloc(1024*10), 1024*100));
}
```

I see a stubs section in objdump

```
0000000100003f94 <__TEXT.__stubs>:
   100003f94:   b0000010        adrp    x16, 100004000 <_main+0x98>
   100003f98:   f9400210        ldr     x16, [x16]
   100003f9c:   d61f0200        br      x16
   100003fa0:   b0000010        adrp    x16, 100004000 <_main+0x98>
   100003fa4:   f9400610        ldr     x16, [x16, #8]
   100003fa8:   d61f0200        br      x16
   100003fac:   b0000010        adrp    x16, 100004000 <_main+0x98>
   100003fb0:   f9400a10        ldr     x16, [x16, #16]
   100003fb4:   d61f0200        br      x16
```

Section:

```
3 __DATA_CONST.__got 00000018  0000000100004000  0000000100004000  00004000  2**3
              CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
```

I'm not sure how to put all of this together in order to link without requiring my team to copy mac specific libs to their system (and I'm sure I'm not allowed to distribute it?). Is there a way I can build a lib that I can distribute and use to cross compile?

Comment: If you want to build on a host system for a completely different target system, you need to set up a *cross compilation* environment. You generally can't just build on one system and transfer it to a completely different system. Especially when it comes to things like system calls which just aren't handled the same on the different systems.

Comment: I'm not sure of the details, but it might be possible to have a library with just symbols that cross compilers can link against, without containing the actual implementation.  But note that the lowest-level parts of MacOS are open-source (e.g. the Darwin kernel); that might include their libc.  IDK if the libc binary would be freely redistributable or not, but I'd expect there's some way to cross-compile C programs for MacOS that only use ISO / POSIX functions.  Of course, you'd also need the right header files, since constants like `O_RDONLY` may be system-specific.

Comment: I didn't follow your post history, can you sum it up? What exactly do you want to do?  Compile that C source on a non-M1 Linux computer and then be able to run the binary on an M1-mac? As already pointed out, you need a cross compiler. Your team will likely have x86_64 compilers that make ELF binaries. Look into a cross compiler or just write POSIX code and distribute the sources with a Makefile.

Comment: @MargaretBloom clang can build ARM assembly on linux and run on mac fine. I got that far in my cross compile adventure. It's the linking to symbols I'm stuck at

Comment: @Stan Of course you can cross-compile if you use cross-compiler (clang + lld). From your question, it's not clear how you were compiling and linking your files (there's no such thing as "post history" on this site). Anyway, as pointed out, if you can't copy the libs, you may try making one or more empty stubs with the name you need and play with the sysroot clang's flag. You may want to automate the task by extracting the name and generating an assembly file that you can cross-compile as a .so and link against.

Comment: @MargaretBloom it appears in private mode I can see my questions sorted by newest. Anyway, I'm not sure how I should do any of what you suggested. For example I'm not sure if I should use the values I see in my binary as is or if a section is replaced at runtime and need to have certain symbols so the dynamic library knows what to replace. I could blindly try things but I rather not guess or reverse engineer unless I really have to. I'll probably stick with a bad implementation that sticks to systemcalls which I figured out earlier

Comment: @PeterCordes I had no luck finding an implementation in here https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/ I saw a define and couldn't find an implementation for that either. Using lldb it seems like the stub uses __DATA_CONST.__got as a lookup table (got=global offset table?) which gets filled in at runtime (I don't see the correct values in binary unless I did something wrong). Using what I did here I don't see the header for the got table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74660777/how-to-cross-compile-arm64-assembly-from-linux-to-mac/74661348#74661348

Comment: I'm not great at assembly but I have a feeling there should be some easy solution where I can say take my raw binary file and name it __DATA_CONST.__got. I have no idea what anything is called or what it might be called in the linker

Comment: Yeah, it's normal that dynamic linking goes through the GOT entry (which gets filled in by the dynamic linker); the shared library gets loaded at a random address so it can't be hard-coded into the binary.  That's why I said you should single-step into it with a debugger, in a running process.