# Cross assemble Linux Arm64 using MacOS clang assembler

Tags: linux, macos, assembly, clang, arm64

I am trying to write Assembly on MacOS using the default `clang` assembler.

I got this small "Hello World" working for MacOS on the same machine:

```
.global _main
.align 2

_main: mov X0, #1
    adr     X1, hello
    mov     X2, #13
    mov     X16, #4
    svc     0

    mov     X0, #0
    mov     X16, #1
    svc     0

hello: .ascii  "Hello World!\n"
```

It is taken from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74659322/why-is-hello-world-in-assembly-for-arm-mac-invalid).

When I assembler it with:

```
clang hello.s
```

I can successfully run it with:

```
./a.out
```

---

Now, I try to follow the "Hello World" for Linux from the book [Programming with 64-Bit ARM Assembly Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0881Z2VJG). It is basically the same program, but the sys-calls is for Linux:

```
.global _start

_start: mov X0, #1
    ldr     X1, =hello
    mov     X2, #13
    mov     X8, #64
    svc     0

    mov     X0, #0
    mov     X8, #93
    svc     0

.data
hello: .ascii  "Hello World!\n"
```

I cannot event assemble this program using `clang hello.s` on MacOS, I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I assume that this error is because I have not told `clang` that it should use Linux as target.

How can I cross assemble the above "Hello World" to Linux Arm64 from MacOS on Arm64 using the built in clang?

I want to be able to run the Linux binary in a Arm64 Docker container on MacOS Arm64.

Comment: The code is missing a `=` sign. Should be `ldr X1, =hello` to load the address. Try if that works better.

Comment: You used `ldr` instead of `adr` in the Linux version.  And not even `ldr     X1, =hello` to tell the assembler to get the address somehow, you asked it to load 8 bytes from memory.  Apparently it doesn't want to expand that as a pseudo-instruction, so it's trying to use a PC-relative addressing mode or something, but it has to reach a potentially long distance into another section?  Not sure what relocation type it thinks it wants.

Comment: @PeterCordes It wants something like `adrp`+`add` with a `.loh AdrpAdd ...` directive, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74677682). But that's just for Darwin targets anyway.

Comment: @Jester thanks, that was my typo. I updated the error message after fixing the typo.

Comment: Try with `-nostdlib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `lld` or some other linker that can output ELF binaries, as Xcode only ships with Apple's `ld64`, which is limited to Darwin targets. Once you have `lld` in your path, you can build your assembly file with:

```
clang --target=arm64-linux-gnu -fuse-ld=lld hello.s -nostdlib
```

Of course, if you want to use libraries or eventually compile C code and include header files, you will have to either find or build an SDK to pass to clang with `--sysroot`. I'm not aware of any standard process for doing this, but I've had some success with just pulling public deb files from Ubuntu/Debian package mirrors and unpacking them into one folder.

Comment: Apple `clang` does not seem to be compatible with `lld`. I get errors like `error: unknown argument '--eh-frame-hdr'` and same for `argument '-EL'`.

Comment: @Jonas `--eh-frame-hdr` and `-EL` are `lld`-specific arguments though. I think you just installed a too-old version of `lld`.

Answer (score 2):

After the answer to Siguza, the difficult part was to find a *linker* that could do the job.

This is what finally worked for me.

Install [macos cross toolchain](https://github.com/messense/homebrew-macos-cross-toolchains) with:

```
brew install aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

After that I have this binary that can be added to PATH:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/11.2.0/bin/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-ld
```

Then I could build the binary with:

```
clang --target=arm64-linux-gnu -fuse-ld=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-ld hello.s -nostdlib
```

And I could verify the binary by using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
ADD a.out /bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/a.out"]
```

Build a container with:

```
docker build -t app .
```

Run it and get the output:

```
docker run app
Hello World!
```